# Load multiple memory mapped files with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, memory-mapped-files

I'm trying to load two memory mapped files,

```
temp = numpy.load(currentDirectory + "\\tmp\\temperature.npy", mmap_mode='r')
salinity = numpy.load(currentDirectory + "\\tmp\\salinity.npy", mmap_mode='r')
```

but Python throws the following error:

```
IOError: Failed to interpret file 'C:\\my\\file\\path\\..\\tmp\\salinity.npy' as a pickle
```

When I load either by itself, it works just fine.

The files that are quite large (~500MB), but otherwise I don't think they are notable.

What might the problem be here?

Comment: Does the same thing happen with smaller files?  It might help if you show the `shape` and `dtype` of these files (when loaded individually).

Comment: Hi @hpaulj , shape = `(1, 102, 720, 1440)` and type = `float32` . I'll give some smaller files a try and see what happens...

Comment: Hi @hpaulj it appears to work fine when I have two small files... I wonder if Im running out of memory to interpret the file?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Both files are large than 5GB.

```
X = np.load(os.path.join(path, '_file1.npy'), mmap_mode='r')
Y = np.load(os.path.join(path, '_file2.npy'), mmap_mode='r')
```

Which operating system are you using? The problem is not with size of the "npy" files but problem is with "\" in path. change your path as:

```
path = '/media/gtx1060/DATA/Datasets'
```